# Why would innoDB lock tables

Tags: mysql, innodb, table-locking, database-engine

I'm using innoDB on AWS.  I keep getting a ton of the following messages in my logs:

Waiting for table level lock

I thought innoDB only did row-level locks. I don't have any lock tables in my code. Does anyone have any idea why this would happen?

Comment: Have a read through http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2012/07/31/innodb-table-locks/

Comment: Since MySQL 5.5 row locking issues became much more problematic (stric?t). Before 5.5, a select was not causing lock, from 5.5 onwards, it does ;(. More info here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-lock-modes.html

Answer (score 3):

There are certain reasons when InnoDB table locks comes into picture:

1) InnoDB is aware of table locks if `innodb_table_locks = 1` (the default) and `autocommit = 0`, and the MySQL layer above InnoDB knows about row-level locks.

You should set `innodb_table_locks=0` and restart MySQL server.

2) While initializing a previously specified `AUTO_INCREMENT` column on a table, InnoDB sets an exclusive lock on the end of the index associated with the AUTO_INCREMENT column. While accessing the auto-increment counter, InnoDB uses a specific `AUTO-INC` table lock mode where the lock lasts only to the end of the current SQL statement, not to the end of the entire transaction. Other clients cannot insert into the table while the `AUTO-INC` table lock is held.

You can refer this blog post as well: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2012/07/31/innodb-table-locks/

Answer (score 0):

There some situations under which innoDB will do table locks (like AUTO-INC) see this article in this regard, and see if applies to you case: [InnoDB table locks](http://mysqldatabaseadministration.blogspot.in/2007/06/innodb-table-locks.html)

Also check if set or set  `innodb_table_locks=0` in MySQL configuration.Refer here for the documentation: [InnoDB Startup Options and System Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_table_locks)